# Problema em retorno após enviar dados! HTML & PHP. Pensei que apareceria o echo quando enviasse os dados, mas nada aparecei

Tags: php, html

[image: Mesmo depois de inserir e enviar dados, ele volta pra tela inicial]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Exercicio 3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php  
$km = $_POST['km'];
$valcombu =$_POST['valcombu'];
$gaston =$_POST['gaston'];

$km = 0;
$valcombu;
$gaston = 0;

$gaston = ($km / 8) * $valcombu;
echo "Você vai gastar R$" .$gaston;
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="km" >Entre com a quilometragem percorrida</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="km">
<br><br>
    <label for="valcombu">Entre com o preço do combustivel</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="valcombu">
<br>            
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
        <input type="reset" name="Resetar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está resetando os valores depois de resgatar os mesmos, faça da seguinte maneira, inserido valores default antes. Coloquei algumas melhorias para evitar mensagens de warning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercicio 3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php  

$km = 0;
$valcombu;
$gaston = 0;


$km = isset($_POST['km']) ? $_POST['km'] : 0;
$valcombu = isset($_POST['km']) ? $_POST['valcombu'] : 0;

$gaston = ($km / 8) * $valcombu;

if(!isset($_POST['km']) && !isset($_POST['valcombu'])) {

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="km" >Entre com a quilometragem percorrida</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="km">
<br><br>
    <label for="valcombu">Entre com o preço do combustivel</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="valcombu">
<br>            
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
        <input type="reset" name="Resetar">
</form>

<?php } ?>

<p><?php echo "Você vai gastar R$" .$gaston; ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ainda não está retornando nada, volta sempre pra mesma tela inicial

Comment: Ele volta para a mesma tela porque o action do form está chamando a mesma tela. Mas se você observar, vai aparecer a mensagem "Você vai gastar R$" com um valor calculado. Você pode criar um outro arquivo que faça esse calculo, e chamar ele no action.

Comment: Então, isso eu sei que deve funcionar, mas o problema é que o exercicio em questão era pra ser feito com o php dentro do html, fora esse estou tendo o mesmo problema com outros 3 exercicios.

Comment: Editei a resposta, tente agora da maneira que especifiquei e veja se atende ao que você está esperando.

Comment: Ainda não está funcionando, até pensei que seria por estar usando o XAMPP, mas mesmo sem ele ainda não volta nada além de uma tela inicial .

Comment: Posta na pergunta os prints das telas que você está recebendo.

Comment: O arquivo está com sua extensão como .php? Sem nada após isso.

Comment: Ahhh, era isso mesmo, obrigado. Tem como fazer o Echo sair embaixo dos dados sem ir pra "outra página" por assim dizer?

Comment: Sim, editei a resposta aqui, coloque a resposta como correta pra dar a pergunta como finalizada

Comment: Ué, mas agora depois que envio as informações ele vai para uma tela em branco

Comment: Estava dentro do if, atualizei.

Comment: Bom, ainda está indo pra uma "Nova pagina" por assim dizer, mas já ajudou muito com o real problema da pergunta, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

tente o código a seguir, o código testado e está 100% funcional

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercicio 3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php  
// Define um valor padrão para o gasto
$gasto = 0;

// Verifica se foi recebido as variaveis post
if(isset($_POST['km']) && isset($_POST['valorDoCombustivel'])) {
    $km = $_POST['km'];
    $valorDoCombustivel = $_POST['valorDoCombustivel'];

    // Atribui um novo valor ao gasto
    $gasto = ($km / 8) * $valorDoCombustivel;
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="km" >Entre com a quilometragem percorrida</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="km">
    <br>

    <label for="valcombu">Entre com o preço do combustivel</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="valorDoCombustivel">
    <br>            

    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
    <input type="reset" name="Resetar">
</form>

<p>Você vai gastar R$ <?php echo $gasto; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Importante: a condição If verifica somente se existe a variável e não se o valor dela é um número, caso seja passado um valor vazio ou não número irá retornar erro, agora você adiciona suas validações conforme necessário.

Espero ter ajudado.